# Discrepancy in pixel size reported by chrome and screen pixels

Tags: css, google-chrome

I was designing a page, and set the size of a div to 100px (80px height + 20px padding-top).

```
.header {
    height: 80px;
    padding-top:20px;
    ...
}
```

---

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        Just another blog
    </div>
    ....
</body>
```

But when rendering in Chrome, and taking a screenshot, I can see using Paint that the size is actually closer to 150px.

I've got a 144dpi screen, and am not sure if it's related to that.
I would've expected that this would get handled fine since it's the size of a div, not an image.

I also followed the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/a/803650/122651), which mentioned a bug in Chrome on high-DPI screens. I tried starting Chrome using the flags mentioned there to force Chrome into high-DPI mode, which fixed the issue. But other sites don't seem to have the same issue that post was referring to, so I'm wondering if there's something different I should be doing via CSS to mitigate this?

[image]

You can see Chrome reporting the div as 100px tall, but Paint measures it as ~150px

I'm using Chrome 49.0.2623.87 m, on Windows 8.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using Paint for web development? Why does it matter what size Paint is telling you the div is? If the height of the div is 100px in Chrome then that's all that matters.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why there's a discrepancy between the size in pixels that Chrome reports and the size in screen pixels.